# Previous screen Bloc call after open new screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am using Bloc pattern in my project, But my previous screen's Bloc still call in my new screen. I have dispose my Bloc but in screen dispose method is not call. Please help to solve this problem.

Bloc file:

```
class ForgotPasswordBloc extends Object {
  final PublishSubject<ForgotPassState> _passStateSubject = new PublishSubject();

  Stream<ForgotPassState> get passStateStream => _passStateSubject.stream;

  void changeState({ForgotPassState state}) => _passStateSubject.sink.add(state);

  forgotPasswordSubmit(String email) async {
    changeState(state: ForgotPassState(status: ForgotPassStatus.CALLING, message: "calling"));
    
      var response = await post(Constant.API_URL+"forgotPassword", body: {
        "email": email,
      });
      ForgotPasswordModal data = ForgotPasswordModal.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      if (data.status == "success") {

        await changeState(state: ForgotPassState(status: ForgotPassStatus.SUCCESS, message: "Success"));
      } else {
        changeState(
            state: ForgotPassState(
                status: ForgotPassStatus.ERROR, message: data.message));
      }
  }

  dispose() {
    print("dispose called==========>");
    _passStateSubject.close();
  }
}
Here I call the bloc method:
 StreamBuilder<ForgotPassState>(
            stream: forgotpass_bloc.passStateStream,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ForgotPassState> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                case ForgotPassStatus.SUCCESS:
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showInformationDialog(context,email_controller.text.trim()));
                  break;
                default:
                  return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
In above code after getting success response my information dialog is open, In dialog I have close button After click on the close button I have open new Screen but in that screen my previous screen dialog is display.
```

Comment: Post a piece of your code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to dispose the bloc in the ui widget, where you generate the bloc instance and not in the bloc class itself

Comment: I also dispose bloc in my ui widget but this is not working. but I got resolved by adding new status none after success status.